# Can you guide me how to set settings so that compiler generate .com file as its TSR program?

Tags: c, interrupt

[c program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa6Ce.png)

I tried to run this program in Turbo c++ but it's not working. It's a TSR(Terminate but Stay Resident) program. To run such programs, these have to be converted into .com file but I do not know how to set Turbo c++ settings for this. Kindly guide.

Comment: Have you looked up `EXE2BIN` utility? I also guess you need to compile with the `SMALL` or possibly `TINY` memory model.

Comment: Woah.. I think you have invented a time machine or something...

Comment: My guess is that 1Mb memory will be enough to run a `TINY` model which is limited to 64Kb. I remember installing my first upgrade to a massive 2Mb - I was sailing!